# Custom Nancy bootstrapper not being called

Tags: c#, nancy

I am building a Nancy based application which uses the `NancyHost` as the embedded web server.

I am also trying to serve some static content, by creating a custom bootstrapper as described in their documentation [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content).
However, the problem I see is that this custom bootstrapper class is never instantiated and the `ConfigureConventions` method is never called. Is there any specific action that I have to do in order to make sure this custom bootstrapper is registered?

The custom bootstrapper code below:

```
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Conventions;
using System;

namespace Application
{
    public class CustomBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions conventions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("client", @"client"));
            conventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("lib", @"lib"));
            base.ConfigureConventions(conventions);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had to pass the reference to my CustomBootstrapper in the NancyHost constructor.

```
var host = new NancyHost(new Uri(JsonHelper.URL), new CustomBootstrapper(), config);
host.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your bootstrapper in another assembly?

Please check IncludeInNancyAssemblyScanning
in
[Documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Bootstrapper)